# Convergence of Lebesgue integral of an indicator function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n(x) = - \frac{1}{n} \mathbb 1_{[0,n]} (x) $ for $n \in \mathbb N$.

(The 1 should be the indicator function.)

- The sequence converges to $-n-1$, right?
- What about the Lebesgue integral of $f_n$? Can anybody show me if it converges, and if yes, to which value?

Comment: Don't understand first bullet. $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions that converges pointwise to the zero function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$. If $x \ge 0$, then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \in [0,n]$ for all $n \ge N$, hence $f_n(x)= - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \ge N$.

Conclusion: $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$.

Furthermore: $ \int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x) dx=- \frac{1}{n}\int_{\mathbb R}1_{[0,n}(x) dx=- \frac{1}{n} \lambda([0,n])=- \frac{1}{n}n=-1$,

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent help! What if $h_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} 1_{[n, + \infty]} (x) $ ? $g_n$ also converges pointwise to 0. With the Lebesgue integral, I'm not sure: We have $\frac{1}{n} \lambda ([n, + \infty]) = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \infty = 1$ Is this correct or not at all?

Comment: Well no...if it really is 1/n times infinity, this is not defined if n goes to infinity...

Answer (score 1):

$$\int f_n\;d\lambda=\int-\frac1n\mathbf1_{[0,n]}\;d\lambda=-\frac1n\int\mathbf1_{[0,n]}\;d\lambda=-\frac1n\lambda([0,n])=-\frac1n\cdot n=-1$$
So it converges to $-1$.

Further note that $f_n\to0$ pointwise, and (off course) $\int0\;d\lambda=0$.

So in this case $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ and $\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\;d\lambda$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\;d\lambda$ are properly defined, but this with:$$\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\;d\lambda\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\;d\lambda$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent help! What if $h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}1_{[n,+∞]}(x)$ ? $h_n$ also converges pointwise to 0. With the Lebesgue integral, I'm not sure: We have $\frac{1}{n} \lambda ([n, + \infty])=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \infty =1$. Is this correct or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n \to0$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{-1}{n}1_{[0,n]}(x) \lambda (dx) = \frac{-1}{n}\lambda([0,n]) = -1 \neq \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 d\lambda$$

so we have an example where we cannot interchange limit and integral.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent help! What if $h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}1_{[n,+∞]}(x)$ ? $h_n$ also converges pointwise to 0. With the Lebesgue integral, I'm not sure: We have $\frac{1}{n} \lambda ([n, + \infty])=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \infty =1$. Is this correct or not at all?

Comment: $1/n. \infty = \infty$, so the sequence of integrals is constant $\infty$, but the limit's integral is $0$. Another case where we cannot interchange integral and limit.

Comment: All right...one last question: what if $d_n(x) = D(x) (cos (\pi x ))^n$ , where $D: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is measurable. Here, I'm a bit lost. The sequence itself takes values 1 to -1, but does not converge. (correct?) What about the Lebesgue integral of $d_n(x)$ ?

Comment: Hint: the lebesgue integral is 0 if the function is 0 almost everywhere.

Comment: Ah, so can we say that since there is a real number $a$ s.t. $cos(a) = 0$, the Lebesgue integral is 0 , too?

Comment: Not really. When is $d_n(x)$ equal to 0?

Comment: Oh, if $x = n - \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: That's not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85765/discussion-between-stman-and-math-qed).